# Angular Ui grid - How to dynamically bind column definitions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a angular ui-grid , I want to control visibility of the columns of my grid externally instead from grid menu.

I tried changing the visible property of the column definition to false, but it isn't hiding the column.

value.displayName-- my column object

```
 angular.forEach($scope.gridApi2.grid.columns, function (x) {
        if (value.displayName == x.displayName) {
            x.visible = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show a plunker with whatever you have done and what exactly is the problem/error

Comment: @NagaSandeep please check with my latest edit, gridApi2 is my ui-grid object